# Limit Amount Of Widgets In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have designed a Wordpress theme and on one of my sidebars there can only be 3 widgets. I need to limit the amount of widgets a user can add to this theme some how.

Any ideas? I can use plugins if necessary

Comment: Is it for cosmetic reason that anything more than 3, the sidebar's look get screwed up?

Comment: @o.k.w: It goes horizontally :)

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of a better answer, might look at a plugin that restricts where widgets get displayed.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/

Comment: Why does this need a plugin? Why does adding a sub-title to a page need a plugin? Why can you not group widgets without a plugin? Why is wordpress so shit?